# Adding unique id in rails4 logger to identify the request and response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

I have added the following rails logger in my worker file.

```
@@logger = Logger.new "log/rest_client.log"
  @@logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
end


begin
  @@logger.debug "The request #{url}"
  response = RestClient.get '#{url}'
  @@logger.debug "Successful response #{response}"
rescue => e
  @@logger.debug "Failure response #{e.message}"
end
```

I want to identify the request and response(success or failure) with the unique id in the logger(rest_client.log).

Now the log is

```
D, [2014-12-09T14:27:18.576498 #29871] DEBUG -- : The request https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/symbols
D, [2014-12-09T14:27:21.547365 #29874] DEBUG -- :Successful response ["btcusd","ltcusd","ltcbtc","drkusd","drkbtc","th1btc"]
```

I want some thing unique to both request and response to identify both belong to the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you control the contents of the log message at each step, you can yourself create and use a unique id every time the request is made. A ID based on timestamp would be unique.

One possible solution:

```
begin
  unique_id = "ID-" + Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
  @@logger.debug "#{unique_id}: The request #{url}"
  response = RestClient.get '#{url}'
  @@logger.debug "#{unique_id}: Successful response #{response}"
rescue => e
  @@logger.debug "#{unique_id}: Failure response #{e.message}"
end
```

Log:

```
D, [2014-12-09T14:27:18.576498 #29871] DEBUG -- : ID-20141209-142718: The request https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/symbols
D, [2014-12-09T14:27:21.547365 #29874] DEBUG -- : ID-20141209-142718: Successful response ["btcusd","ltcusd","ltcbtc","drkusd","drkbtc","th1btc"]
```